# Python updated list through a class

Tags: python, list, class

Im trying to have a list which adds to it whenever a function is called. For example if you push button 1 a function is called which adds 5 to listone or if you push button2 the number 10 is added to listone.And I want list one to continuously show the results when it gets updated.
For example  I create a class
Class MyClass(object)
    def **init**(self):
        listone=[]
        then button1
        button2 ..

Comment: We don't even know what gui framework you're working with.  I think you're going to need to show us some minimal code illustrating your problem

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this help?

```
class MyClass(object):
    my_list = []
    def __init__(self, initial_list):
        self.my_list = initial_list
    def button_1(self):
        self.my_list = [ele + 5 for ele in self.my_list]
        print(self.my_list)
    def button_2(self):
        self.my_list = [ele + 10 for ele in self.my_list]
        print(self.my_list)
```

Result:

```
>>> a = MyClass([1,2,3])
>>> a.button_1()
[6, 7, 8]
>>> a.button_2()
[16, 17, 18]
```